# PHP Change Page?

Tags: php, url, header, location

I have found out the bad news about header(), so I am no longer using it, because now my website doesn't work..

Is there any other simple way to change pages automatically?

Comment: what the bad news are about header() ?

Comment: By change you mean redirection?

Comment: For those of us that aren't aware, could you expand on "the bad news" about `header()`?

Comment: Bad news about header() is that you cannot use it after html.. I would like to change pages automatically,

Comment: I was using <?php header('Location: page.php'); ?> before.

Comment: use a FrontContoller: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html :-) More to the point... buffer your output instead of printing it directly to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean like redirect?
you can also use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;
URL=http://www.yahoo.com">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It says I can't accept your answer until 11 minutes passes.. so I will wait.

Answer (score 2):

Try javascript redirection

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.location = "new_page.php";
</script>
```

or you can use meta-refresh (many examples in google).

If you can't use header in your script, just add ob_start(); at the beginning and then you can use it AFTER html.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you'd do well to re-work your code so you do a redirection *before* sending a bunch of HTML that's never going to be seen. And if you do that - you can use `header()`, which causes less delay for your end users, reduces processing all round, and is search-engine friendly! Win-win-win.